# sequential execution of links on jsp page which are dependent on each other

Tags: jsp, servlets

i have a jsp page(containing links to other jsp's) :

```
link1
link2
link3
.
.
link16
```

These url's contains scripts that persist data in database using hibernate

now,data generated by link8 is dependent on link1 and

time taken by link1 to complete script is 1 hr and that of link8 is 5 min

the user clicks on all links(sequentially) within 1 min.

so how to make sure that link8 is opened only after link1 is done with data persisting so that i dont miss the data generation in link8

i suppose the only solution is converting jsp scripts to java functions.
since functions execute sequentially.Thanks

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead (what have you tried so far).

Comment: i want more like a thread that executes scripts in jsp's in sequential fashion